# Prepending nightmare

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, filemaker

I wrote some code to connect with FileMaker Server and ask for a new record to be created on the backend server.  This portion works fine and the result contains unexpected text that does not show up in a browser.  I couldn't get the find operations to work by looking at the tree in a browser so I ended up printing the tags and attributes out and every tag attribute pair has this format:

Tag:  {http://www.filemaker.com/xml/fmresultset}error Attrib:  {'code': '0'}

In my code below I'm having to put the fully qualified tag into the code to get the first find to work.  This makes it harder to figure out the xPath to the object that I want to get from the XML.  The second find below doesn't work since I can't figure out the path.  The path should be /resultset/record/ and the attribute is record-id.  Anybody have an idea of what is happening.  Why is the fmresultset document prepended to every tag?

```
url = self.getBaseURL( machineID, file, lay ) + fields + "&-new"
result = self.sendURL( url )

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(result)
self.printXML( root )

base = "{http://www.filemaker.com/xml/fmresultset}"
find = root.find( base + "error" )
error = find.attrib[ 'code' ]

recID = 0
if ( error == '0' ):
    find = root.find( base + "resultset" + base + "/record" )
    recID = find.attrib[ 'record-id' ]
```

Keith

Answer (score 0):

OK... You mentioned the word namespace and I figured it out.  This uses the element version of root.

```
def getXMLValue( self, root, path, value ):
    ns = {'fmrs': 'http://www.filemaker.com/xml/fmresultset' }
    find = root.find( path, ns )
    value = find.attrib[ value ]
    return value

def getError ( self, root ):
    return self.getXMLValue ( root, "fmrs:error", 'code' )

def getRecID ( self, root ):
    return self.getXMLValue ( root, "fmrs:resultset/fmrs:record", 'record-id' )
```

This code correctly returns the correct value.  I was expecting something like.  Create an instance of the class then call setNamespace().  I'm having to put all these references to fmrs which I would rather not do but this solves the issues and the code isn't horrible to read.

Thanks for the assist.

-keith